# Need word similar to 'fixer' but for a legit professional context

Tags: single-word-requests

As of late, my primary work duties have involved being the one on my team who knows the right people, knows how to get things done or at least moving, figures out what people and groups want and figures out how to get it to them in the expectation I can call on their assistance in future tasks that need to be done.  It requires a strong skill at building and maintaining relationships, keeping track (if only in one's own head) of weight and amount of favors, and a darned hefty bit of technical knowledge (for when no one else is available and one has to do the work independently).

In private conversations I jest that I've become the 'fixer' in the group, but as I look to formalize this state of affairs, I am concerned that the term's negative connotation might be inappropriate as a professional, legitimate employment position title.

Thesaurus.com makes a number of suggestions, but none of them feel right.  I wonder if there is another term similar that captures much the same denotation without the negative connotation.  I am also open to suggestions that despite it's connotation, 'fixer' may in fact be the best option.

[Added]

**arbiter, arbitrator, attorney** -- imply legal work; my work is in IT.

**intermediary, mediator, negotiator** -- imply the primary role of a position is negotiation, I perceive it more as arranging resources, leveraging social capital, and, as needed, doing the work one's self.  Negotiation plays little role as by the time I'm involved, what is needed is what is needed.

**middleman / middle person** -- overlooks that the position does at times require being very hands-on, plus has negative connotations of a non-worker, someone who gets others to do the work.

**power broker** -- also bears significant connotation baggage.  I implicitly have no authority or power; what I get done, I get done by my own merit or by wielding purely social influence.

Comment: What options from the thesaurus have you rejected, and what's wrong with them?

Comment: the **oil** for the machine

Comment: If you're using agile methodology, particularly Scrum, there's already a role for this: Scrum Master. Other agile systems have similar roles. From the suggestions posted below, facilitator is probably the most apt.

Comment: Co-ordinator or co-ordination specialist?

Comment: I am in the same situation. The best I can think of is special projects manager.

Comment: "I am concerned that the term's negative connotation might be inappropriate as a professional, legitimate employment position title." There is nothing whatsoever legit about "you scratch my back and I'll scratch yours." It is a mostly criminal and always filthy practice. You are only part of the problem, not in any way part of some solution. The term you want is *parasite*, sometimes euphemized as "manager without portfolio." But you could at least sound legit by getting a law degree.

Answer (score 2):

From [Thesuarus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/):

[Troubleshooter](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/troubleshooter)(n): One who finds and fixes issues or problems.

> This is LRWerewolf, our number one troubleshooter.

[Factotum](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/factotum)(n): Jack-of-all-trades

And from personal insight:

[Facilitator](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/facilitator)(n): One who makes things easier, or just makes them happen.

> I'm the facilitator for the department; you need something done, I can help make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider

> ex·pe·dite ˈekspəˌdīt/ verb verb: expedite; 3rd person present:
>   expedites; past tense: expedited; past participle: expedited; gerund
>   or present participle: expediting
>
> ```
> make (an action or process) happen sooner or be accomplished more quickly.
> "he promised to expedite economic reforms"
> synonyms: speed up, accelerate, hurry, hasten, step up, quicken, precipitate, dispatch; advance, facilitate, ease, make easier,
> ```
>
> further, promote, aid, push through, urge on, boost, stimulate, spur
>   on, help along, catalyze, fast-track
>       "our legal assistants can help expedite the paperwork"

This is most often used with reference to project management (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expediting) but might be useful for your purposes.